# Info about the semantics in str_extract in R? (With an example)

Tags: r, dplyr, gsub, stringr

I want to understand how to use the semantics in str_extract in the stringr package in R.

I have strings that are written like this and `11_3_S11.html"`
and I would like to extract from them the value after the first underscore.
I mean, I want to remove the number `3`.

`files = c("11_3_S11.html")`

I would appreciate it if someone can explain the logic or send me a link with all the semantics.

Thank you for your time

Comment: You mean you want a link to the online help? [https://stringr.tidyverse.org/reference/str_extract.html](https://stringr.tidyverse.org/reference/str_extract.html)

Comment: Or in general start with regular expressions at https://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: Thanks @RonakShah, your comments are always useful to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In base R, you can use `sub` to extract a number after 1st underscore.

```
sub('\\d+_(\\d+)_.*', '\\1', files)
#[1] "3"
```

where `\\d+` refers to 1 or more number.

`()` is referred as capture group to capture the value that we are interested in.

---

You can use the same regex in `str_match` if you want to use `stringr`.

```
stringr::str_match(files, '\\d+_(\\d+)_.*')[, 2]
[1] "3"
```

Comment: Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1):

Using look around.

```
str_extract("11_3_S11.html", '(?<=_)\\d(?=_)')
[1] "3"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I highly appreciate